# How can I implement this dual-gradient menu design?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a design for a menu on a web page, but I'm stuck.

The concept is this: there are two vertical columns, a menu and a content container. The menu's background is a linear gradient from white to grey. The content's background is a linear background from grey to white. The menu contains a navigation list of variable height. When a navigation item is selected, it takes a background that blends with the color of the content container besides it.

Here's an image to show what I mean:

[image]

Here are the constraints:

- some of the elements in the menu can expand or contract. I don't know the size of the menu at all times
- the number of elements can change
- but the exact gradient colours will not change
- I don't know the height of the entire web page / content area
- non-selected menu items need to not blend into the gradient of the nav container

Is it possible to do this with CSS alone? I looked into playing with the clip property, but it involved me absolutely positioning the elements and the text within them, which I can't do because I don't know how many there will be. I can't think of anything that fits the constraints.

Edit: We could modify the design to keep the non-selected menu items in white, then start the white-to-grey gradient after the menu elements finish. But I can't see a way to do this, as the columns can vary in height.

Comment: Do you already have a DOM structure for your page?

Comment: Yes. The current page implements the menu as a ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the background for the whole ul, then you cannot make it transparent again for single ones. So you need to apply it to every single li and set the `background-attachment` to `fixed`:

```
ul li{
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, red 0%, blue 100%);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, red 0%, blue 100%);
   background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I made a JSFiddle which shows this implemented:

http://jsfiddle.net/kLD98/1/

Please look at `li.space`, which isn't perfect yet. Maybe someone else has got an idea to fix this, because I guess the gradients look well already.

Appendix: Please have a look at @Bergis comment and his attached JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/kLD98/9/) which puts the need of using `li.space` aside.

Comment: The only solution for this I can imagine, is setting `overflow` to `auto` for the content area, so that you don't have to scroll the background at all. If that is not what you wanted, then my approach is probably not suitable for your needs.

Comment: No, my mistake, this is the working solution. Even if the content is larger than the viewport, and I scroll, the background doesn't seem to 'stick'. As for li.space, I fixed it by adding overflow: hidden to the ul.

Comment: Ah, just discovered that because the ul is absolutely positioned, it can't force the main element to expand. As such, I won't be able to use it. That's a pity. This is still the correct solution to the requirements I outlined, though, so I'm still marking it as 'accepted'.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye: The absolute is just for making it the left column, you can use your own approach for that.

Comment: @YMMD: The li.space could be done with a "::after". Yet, some small improvements in http://jsfiddle.net/kLD98/8/ Also, the other way round (not setting to transparent, but to different gradient) works without li.space: http://jsfiddle.net/kLD98/9/

Comment: Oh, your second example seems to be ideal, @Bergi, because it doesn't contain the stupid `li.space`. This works awesomely for a fix attached gradient over the whole site, because you can simply show only the cropped part of the 100% stretched gradient. There is no need to "cut a hole" into the ul, as you mentioned in your own answer. This seems to be the perfect solution for this case, so I will update my answer to emphasize your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I fear it is not possible without absolute measurement. Having a background on an element, you can't cut a transparent hole in it for a subelement with pure CSS.

Comment: That was my first thought, but the non-selected menuitems need to blend with the rest of the navigation container.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see (and read) that. The white-grey is hardly visible on my screen, you might strengthen that for the example. I hope I can come back with another answer...

Comment: @Edit - this was what I feared. I may just end up using JS for the effect and gracefully degrading to a pure-white left column for non-JS browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Set the menu item gradient to the same gradient style as the main block, and add a vertical offset of -Xpx to the menu item style.

From this [Apple developer page](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html).

Comment: But how would this work exactly? I don't know the vertical position of an element, so I can't determine what colours the gradient starts and ends at for any particular element.

Comment: yet, how can he know the vertical offset - without absolute positioning, in pure CSS?

Comment: Not in pure CSS, no - I didn't see that requirement. Either explicitly define the menu item heights (won't work with expandable elements and bleugh), or just write some javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an amazing article on css gradients by Chris

http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: how does that article help for the question?

Comment: did you try?
it works it have tried
look at examples
[link]http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

Comment: I don't have any problem with the gradient syntax. It's the 'blending' effect (where the list element gains the color to its right) that's causing me trouble.